# Kafka Zookeeper installation issue

Tags: apache-kafka, windows-8.1

Following the instructions from https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart.

On MingW32 console on Windows 8 64 bit, it produces this error.

```
$ bin/windows/zookeeper-server-start.bat config/zookeeper.properties
./zookeeper-server-start.bat: line 1: @echo: command not found
./zookeeper-server-start.bat: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./zookeeper-server-start.bat: line 2: `rem Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more'
```

How to correctly install Kafka? Looked at some other SO posts about similar issues. Could not find solution for this particular error.

Comment: just use linux :)

Comment: Used to. But right now I can't.

Comment: What version of Kafka?

Comment: @vahid version 0.11.0.0

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is you are running the Windows scripts. In a MinGW environment you need to run the Linux commands. E.g.,

`bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties`

Windows scripts are for when you run Kafka using a Windows Command Prompt.